# Inconsistent teachings on how to choose a non basic variable to enter the basis (primal simplex)

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, reduced-costs, primal-simplex

During the primal simplex algorithm, a non-basic variable must be chosen to enter the basis.

Many resources on the subject choose a variable based solely on its coefficient in the row of the tableau corresponding to the objective, whereas others calculate reduced costs before making a choice.

Why is there not consistency, and is one more popular in practice?

Comment: The coefficient of $x$ in the objective row of a simplex tableau is the reduced cost of $x.$

Comment: Is there multiple definitions for reduced cost?  In [this video](https://youtu.be/M8POtpPtQZc?t=378), they calculate c_j - z_j where z_j is the dot product of c_B and the j-th column of the tableau.  In [this video](https://youtu.be/iwDiG2mR6FM) they just choose based on the coefficient alone.

Comment: Maybe the c_B and the coefficients of the basis variables in the objective row are two different things?

Comment: I think I see where I went wrong.  Thanks @prubin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you choose something with a negative reduced cost, the simplex algorithm "works".  See https://people.orie.cornell.edu/dpw/orie6300/Lectures/lec13.pdf for examples of ways you can choose the entering variable based on how much work you want to do.  You can't just base it on the original cost: it has to be based on the reduced cost.  Normally, this is the value in the cost row of the tableau if you are doing the full tableau method; if you are doing a more compact approach, then the reduced cost might need to be calculated (hence the value of the "first negative reduced cost" approach: you don't calculate all the reduced costs).

Comment: Welcome back! ${}$

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I think the confusion came from seeing both the "compact" approach and the alternative, and not realizing the difference.

Comment: Can it happen that in an intermediate simplex iteration we see more than one entering variables, however for one of them there is no leaving variable indicating unboundedness and for the other there is a leaving variable.